# Map's key as pointer to struct? (use-cases)

Tags: pointers, go

Given a struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar int
}
```

**option 1**, Map's key: `struct value`

```
map[Foo]bool
```

**option 2**, Map's key: `pointer to struct`

```
map[*Foo]bool
```

---

Would there be situations that I *must* pick **option 2**? I.e:

1. memory efficiency?
2. huge struct value?

In general, what are the use-cases where its plausible of having map's key as `pointer to struct`?

Comment: In your example using pointer will be likely slower. The size of pointer is the same as size of Vertex, pointers makes GC work harder and some operations on pointers are slower because of write barriers required for GC.

Comment: @kostya ah ha! thanks for the insights ;)

Comment: @kostya Say if I have a bunch of values underneath the struct, in that case I should I go for pointer ?

Comment: @Roylee but how will you use a pointer as a key? will you keep a separate map to keep keys -> pointers?

Comment: @OneOfOne Okay, I think I understand what you are try to imply now. Map uses value of its key for comparisons, if key is a struct type, its contents will be compared. Hence, unless the size of struct is large, then probably we should use pointer, and separate map to keep keys as you mentioned above. Else, we will always go for option 1. am i correct?

Comment: @Roylee yeah, because you really can't use a pointer as a key like that unless you keep track of the pointers somehow (aka another map or a slice), which would really defeat the point.

Comment: The only use case for pointer map keys I can think of is when you can guarantee that equal objects always have the same address (and these objects are relatively large). This might turn out faster and use less memory if you de-duplicate all your objects once and later only reference them by pointer. Still it is hard to say without benchmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that specific case, a pointer wouldn't really work, because for example:

```
func main() {
    m1, m2 := map[Vertex]int{}, map[*Vertex]int{}
    a, b := Vertex{10}, Vertex{10}
    m1[a], m2[&a] = 10, 10

    fmt.Println(m1[a], m1[b], m1[a] == m1[b])
    fmt.Println(m2[&a], m2[&b], m2[&a] == m2[&b])
    fmt.Printf("%p %p", &a, &b)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/nPAjEz_3K1)

// edit after the question got edited

Only reasons to use a pointer is if the struct's contents aren't comparable (aka has a slice or a map, etc) or if it's too large that using it by value is causing performance issues.

IMHO, your current case should be using a value not a pointer.

Comment: I have rephrased my question, apologize that my question was a little vague initially.

Comment: By the way, would you mind to elaborate why pointer is a better option if struct's contents aren't comparable?

Comment: @Roylee because they can't be used a key then, map keys must be comparable.